# Cannot install Skype on ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10

I tried to install skype on my ubuntu 10.10 resulting in the following error. I even made changes to sources.list adding maverick partner. Still cannot get it to install

```
  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     skype : Depends: ia32-libs (>= 20080808) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: lib32asound2 (> 1.0.22) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: lib32gcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: lib32stdc++6 (>= 4.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
    E: Broken packages
```

When i try to install ia32-libs. This is what i am getting

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: lib32gcc1 but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.3.6-2) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: lib32z1 but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: lib32stdc++6 but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: lib32asound2 but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: lib32bz2-1.0 but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: lib32ncurses5 but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: lib32v4l-0 but it is not going to be installed
```

Comment: @Abdul this type of question belongs on SuperUser.com or ubuntu.stackexchange. see the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 1):

What this simply means, you need to download these libraries in order for skype to run properly.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman when i try to install ia32-libs alone. it's again asking for some dependencies. I even tried installing using deb. it falied too.

Comment: @Adbul Kader, yes, you have to make sure that everything you install, if it requires dependencies, install them. That's the beauty of it all.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman I tried to install packages one by one. At last stuck at this  The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.8) but 2.12.1-0ubuntu10.2 is to be installed

Answer (score 1):

Start Synaptic Package Manager and filter for broken packages. Uninstall the broken packages. Reload the software sources. Try installing skype again.